# Exact differential equations conundrum

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I'm studying EDE's from 'Advanced Engineering mathematics' by 'Michael Greenberg'. I pretty much understood the procedure adopted to know if there exists a function $F(x,y)$ as a solution to the EDE. However, I fail to understand the assumption of $x$ and $y$ to be independent variables in the beginning of the argument. I mean, in the end we often find an implicit or explicit solution of $x$ and $y$, relating one to the other and yet here we are, "assuming" both the variables to be independent of each other all the way. How does that make any sense? For all I know, the very procedure would fail badly if both the variables are dependent as there would be no meaning then of the partial derivatives in the arguments that follow. So, how does it all make any sense? Isn't it all very contradictory to assume one thing and find just the opposite in the end ?

The argument that would fail if $x$ and $y$ become dependent:

\begin{equation}
df=A\,dx+B\,dy=0 \tag{1}
\end{equation}
Now
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{df}{dx}=A+B\,\dfrac{dy}{dx}
\end{equation}

Therefore $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}=A$ since in the partial differential case $dy=0$.

Similarly, $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}=B$.

Answer (score 2):

The solutions to an exact equation are the level curves of a two-variable function, $z=F(x,y)$.  As far as $z$ is concerned, $x$ and $y$ are independent variables.  But when you take a level curve of $F$, by setting $F(x,y) = k$ for some constant $k$, you impose a condition on $x$ and $y$ by saying they need to be on this curve.  In that case, knowing $x$ tells you something about $y$, but only because you've insisted they be on the same level curve.  So $x$ and $y$ are independent, in regards to the surface $z=F(x,y)$ but dependent when you restrict to a level-curve.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by a level curve. Can you elaborate your point a bit more?

Comment: The graph of a two-variable function $z=f(x,y)$ is some sort of surface.  If you fix a value of $z=k$, then the equation $k=f(x,y)$ is a level curve of the surface; you're slicing the surface with the plane $z=k$,  If you plot a bunch of level curves of the surface, you get a contour map of the topography of the surface.  In this context, each contour is a solution of the DE.  The variables are independent when considered in $z=f(x,y)$, but dependent upon each other when you restrict $z=k$.

Comment: But do we not know right from the beginning that z=k? Do we not know right from the beginning that x and y are really dependent on one another?

Comment: Yes.  But the equation we're solving is really $dz = 0$.  When we go looking for $z$, we forget about the $0$.  Setting $dz=0$ is what causes the dependency.  So we find $z=\psi$ first, and then integrate $0$.  When we set them back equal to each other $\psi=C$, we re-introduce the dependency.

Answer (score 1):

When one takes a partial derivative of a function of two or more variables, one holds all variables constant except the variable with respect to which one is taking the partial derivative.  To see a visual example consider the function

\begin{equation}
f(x,y)=x^2y+y
\end{equation}

Suppose we hold $y$ constant at the value $y=1$. The diagram below show the surface graph of $f(x,y)$ as well as the intersection of the surface with the plane $y=1$. As you would expect, the intersection of the two surfaces is a parabola.

When you take $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y)$ you are finding the slope of a tangent line to that parabolic intersection.

The particular parabola will change is $y$ is set to a different constant value, but the slope of the parabola will always satisfy the equation

\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y)=2xy
\end{equation}

for whichever $(x,y)$.

[image: Graphs of z=x^2y+y and y=1]

Comment: Thank you sir for your explanation but my question is more like: " if the y term itself in f(x,y)  happens to be a function of x, then how can we possibly come up with anything such as a partial derivative w.r.t. X or y for that matter?"

Comment: In the context of exact differential equations there is some potential function $z=f(x,y)$ where $x$ and $y$ are _independent_ variables. In such a context $y$ is _not_ a function of $x$.

Comment: Exactly. We assume that y is not a function of x because of that argument. But we very well know that in the end we always get a solution in x and y, relating each to the other in the equation. This implies that x and y are certainly not independent variables as there is evidently a well defined mathematical relationship between the 2, in which case why do we assume them to be independent in our approach right from the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm thoroughly confused in this matter now

[image]

Comment: At this point, it in fact sounds all too confusing. Look at this way. If we assume that x and y are independent variables, then we shouldn't really have any problem in integrating Adx +Bdy=0 because it would in a way be nothing but partial integration. And that would create yet another contradiction because it would result into an equation relating x and y, which would mean they  were really dependent on one another. So, what is really going on here? I think I'd like to have a good overview of the whole process now for it seems extremely mind boggling!